# Req.files is always empty in Express app using Multer

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I am using multer as a middleware to my `express app` for uploading files on the server but it doesn't seem to work properly, every post request I send with either postman or curl has an empty files array in it.

I have already set the headers to 'Content-Type':`'multipart/form-data'` when I send the request

**app.js**

lines:12-43

```
const app = express();
const fileStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'images/');
  },
  Skipfilename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + '-' + file.originalname);
  }
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
   file.mimetype === 'audio/mp3' ||
   file.mimetype === 'image/aug' ||
   file.mimetype === 'image/jpg'
   ) {
    cb(null, true);
  }else {
   cb(null, false);
  }
  };

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()); // x-www-form-urlencoded <form>
 app.use(bodyParser.json()); // application/json

 app.use(
  multer({ storage: fileStorage, fileFilter: fileFilter }).any()
 );

 app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));
```

**routes/admin.js**

lines:5-12

```
const router = express.Router();
router.post('/upload',adminController.upload);
module.exports = router;
```

**controllers/admin.js**

```
exports.upload = (req, res, next) => {  
const files= req.files
console.log(req)
res.status(200).json({ files:files});
}
```

**UPDATE**
Screenshots of the postman request

[Request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty80K.png)

[Request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GjNS.png)

Comment: can you paste postman request here?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur i just uploaded my postman request

Answer (score 0):

It started working after I changed the mp3 mimetype to the correct mimetype of audio/mpeg.But it isn't a compact solution